# Android Java startActivity after onLongClickListener() in RecycleView

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to go `UpdateLanguageActivity` when I press a long click on each row of `RecyvleView`. But I can't create `new Intent()` in this context. I tried to google for the result, but there are only `onLongClickListener()` with `ListView`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't upload screenshots of your code, use code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `Context` to save you some headaches.

```
private Context context;

public MyViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
     this.context = context
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your support. It works fine now on my side.